# Biblioteca cliente para web services REST em Java

Tags: java, web-service, rest

Estou em um projeto no qual é necessário acessar um web service REST e gostaria de saber qual é a biblioteca Java mais usada para acessar esse tipo de recurso de uma maneira fácil.

Sei que é possível inclusive fazer tudo na mão usando as classes padrões do Java, mas procuro algo que simplifique um pouco o trabalho, e também conhecer qual é o padrão de mercado para isso.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Outra boa opção é o [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) da JBoss. Além de implementar o padrão de Client do JAX-RS 2.0 (ou seja, é possível fazer chamadas com o mesmo código que @utluiz demonstrou para o Jersey), a biblioteca possui sua própria API baseada em *proxies*.

Exemplo da [documentação](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html):

```java
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://example.com/base/uri");
ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = (ResteasyWebTarget)target;

SimpleClient simple = rtarget.proxy(SimpleClient.class);
client.putBasic("hello world");
```

Onde `SimpleClient` é uma interface anotada (pode ser inclusive a mesma do servidor):

```java
public interface SimpleClient {
   @PUT
   @Path("basic")
   @Consumes("text/plain")
   void putBasic(String body);

   // ... Demais métodos
}
```

---

Algumas outras opções além do [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) e [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)

- [**Apache CXF**](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html): Também implementa JAX-RS 2.0 e uma API baseada em *proxies*;
- [**Spring Framework**](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/): Possui facilidades para [consumir Web Services RESTFul](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) no bom e velho padrão Spring utilizando [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).
- [**Restfulie**](http://restfulie.caelum.com.br/): da galera da [Caelum](http://www.caelum.com.br/). Solução limpa e pequena, lembra o VRaptor.
- [**Restlet**](http://restlet.org/): Mais uma [Client API](http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/core/resource/client) baseada em *proxies*, essa biblioteca vem se popularizando do lado *server*.

Finalmente, enquanto isso não é necessariamente prático, você sempre pode usar APIs cruas de HTTP para consumir serviços REST. [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), etc. Isso te dá mais controle em troca de código bem mais extenso (e suscetível a erros).

Para um [projetinho](http://sfcb.7rtc.com) *Open Source* / artigo que estou escrevendo junto com um colega, resolvemos codificar um método que faz *upload* de imagens para o Facebook na unha (*POST* com encode *multipart/form-data*) e comparar com o código de uma biblioteca especializada ([RestFB](http://restfb.com/)). Você pode ver a diferença de tamanho e complexidade dos métodos [`publicarRestFB`](https://bitbucket.org/7RTC/sfcb/src/081c14375ccc2306755c201f3ed025b0edce0657/src/main/java/br/com/javamagazine/sfcb/negocio/ServicoImagensFB.java?at=master#cl-70) *vs* [`publicarGraphAPI`](https://bitbucket.org/7RTC/sfcb/src/081c14375ccc2306755c201f3ed025b0edce0657/src/main/java/br/com/javamagazine/sfcb/negocio/ServicoImagensFB.java?at=master#cl-82) para sentir o drama.

Answer (score 7):

Eu não posso afirmar se é o framework mais usado (isso é muito discutível), mas eu uso o [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#client), a [implementação de referência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_refer%C3%AAncia) da API JAX-RS. Ele implementa tanto a parte do servidor quanto a parte do cliente.

Veja um exemplo de uso da *Client API*:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9998").path("resource");

Form form = new Form();
form.param("x", "foo");
form.param("y", "bar");

MyJAXBBean bean =
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
        MyJAXBBean.class);
```

Comment: Apenas linkando a [documentação do Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#client) e lembrando que para o cliente só é necessário o `jersey-client` e opcionalmente um *connector* ([guia](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#client-jdk) para o maven). Na inocência, em uma  situação há alguns tempos atrás, fizemos uma lambança no `Classpath` tentando configurar o *client*, sendo que o próprio *App Server* já disponibiliza tudo o que era necessário através de uma *shared library* (escondida, mas existente) :D.

Answer (score 1):

Neste [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/f474c433-66a8-4e02-92fb-32c9cdd6ad0e/entry/criando-um-webservice-restful-em-java?lang=en) há um passo-a-passo de um 'Hello World' utilizando [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) na implementação de  WebService Restful em Java.

Comment: Só uma nota: a pergunta se refere a uma biblioteca **cliente** mas tutorial indicado fala sobre como criar o serviço no servidor.

Comment: O conteúdo relevante que pode ser encontrado no [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/f474c433-66a8-4e02-92fb-32c9cdd6ad0e/entry/criando-um-webservice-restful-em-java?lang=en) deverá ser colocado no corpo da resposta. Respostas só com link tendem a ser fechadas porque se o link deixar de estar disponível a resposta deixa de ser válida ou contribuir com algo útil.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo a biblioteca **org.apache.httpcomponents**

Caso você utilize **maven** no seu projeto, fica aqui as dependencias

```xml
<!-- Httpclient: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Common-HttpClient: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Exemplo de utilização**

```
public String doRequestPost(String aRota) throws HttpException, IOException {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            PostMethod httpPost = new PostMethod("http://%s:%s/"+aRota);
            httpPost.addParameter("nome", "valor");
            httpclient.executeMethod(httpPost);
            return httpPost.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```