# Dúvida tecnologia para construção de WebApi Rest em Java

Tags: java, rest

Estou postando este tópico para verificar pela experiência de vocês qual tecnologia estão utilizando para a construção de WebApi Rest em java.

Quais bibliotecas? Quais técnicas? Quais vantagens e desvantagens da tecnologia.

Sou iniciante neste assunto e gostaria de entender melhor o que está sendo utilizado e por onde começar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Biblioteca cliente para web services REST em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2389/biblioteca-cliente-para-web-services-rest-em-java)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Um pouco genérica sua pergunta, por conta da onda dos microservices o que eu vejo que tem sido muito usando é SpringBoot, geralmente com jetty ou tomcat embarcado, eu particularmente gosto é bem produtivo em poucos minutos vc já tem um endpoint pra chamar.

As vantagens é que é facilmente escalável, é configurável  via annotation é e tem tmb os actuators que eu gosto bastante.

Em termos de libs não tem mt o que falar com exceção das libs mandatórias do Spring Boot o restante varia muito do que vc quer usar.

Não entendi muito bem a parte de técnicas que vc mencionou.

Acho que você poderia começar pelo getting started do Spring Boot mas é importante que você tenha um nivel legal de Java antes de ir para essa etapa.